# Get latest videos of multiple YouTube channels via YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

I'm currently building a web-app which will display the last videos of a youtube channel. My problem is, that the YouTube-API only allows 100 requests per day, which are way less than I need.

So my Idea was to request the videos every 20 minutes or so from every user and then cache them somewhere to display later on.

Is there a way to select multiple videos per channel for multiple channels in a single request?

Greetings
Alex

Comment: Why dont you just request an increase of your quota?

Comment: Problem is: it's not unlimited scalable. Also I don't have a company, which is necessary to request more qouta...

Comment: I dont have a company and I have a quota  its not needed

Comment: [hacker confirmed]

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by that statement?   Have you tried applying for a quota extension?

Comment: Yes i have, but the company name was an obligatory field in the form and i didn't want to cheat

Comment: Write NA in that field  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/a  It would be better for you to go though the proper channels then to try and go around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution to your problem, but it's [quite involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55794936/8327971) since is about a completely different application model:

Instead of regularly pulling -- at a constant rate, but unsatisfactory due to limitations imposed by default quotas -- a channel's uploads list via the API's [search endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) (or the [playlistItems endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) queried for the channel's [uploads list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55652297/8327971)), make use of the so-called [**API push notifications**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications).

This solution implies entirely different upfront requirements, but, if you really need *real time* updates, then that will suit you more effectively.